# how do I get the post method for a website that doesn't provide posts in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, curl

I want to get data in the form of a list on the website https://gmail.inputekno.com/ by scraping
but when I check, the website doesn't provide post requests, is there a way to work around this? thx u

[image]

I have tried like this but failed

```
import requests

cookies = {
    '_ga': 'GA1.1.1869494453.1672283765',
    '__gads': 'ID=e350f661fb3c1b6a-22c8b78c11d900b8:T=1672283764:RT=1672283764:S=ALNI_MYcfleQdj417a3BQakIyzzrp83MdQ',
    '__gpi': 'UID=00000b9a196b924e:T=1672283764:RT=1672283764:S=ALNI_MZ4UaRvjE4GzR-k0Na5Jj-HBksD4w',
    '_ga_R3D1879B9V': 'GS1.1.1672283764.1.1.1672284364.0.0.0',
}

headers = {
    'authority': 'gmail.inputekno.com',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    # 'cookie': '_ga=GA1.1.1869494453.1672283765; __gads=ID=e350f661fb3c1b6a-22c8b78c11d900b8:T=1672283764:RT=1672283764:S=ALNI_MYcfleQdj417a3BQakIyzzrp83MdQ; __gpi=UID=00000b9a196b924e:T=1672283764:RT=1672283764:S=ALNI_MZ4UaRvjE4GzR-k0Na5Jj-HBksD4w; _ga_R3D1879B9V=GS1.1.1672283764.1.1.1672284364.0.0.0',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Not?A_Brand";v="8", "Chromium";v="108", "Google Chrome";v="108"',
    'sec-ch-ua-arch': '""',
    'sec-ch-ua-bitness': '"64"',
    'sec-ch-ua-full-version-list': '"Not?A_Brand";v="8.0.0.0", "Chromium";v="108.0.5359.125", "Google Chrome";v="108.0.5359.125"',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?1',
    'sec-ch-ua-model': '"Nexus 5"',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Android"',
    'sec-ch-ua-platform-version': '"6.0"',
    'sec-ch-ua-wow64': '?0',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'document',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'navigate',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'none',
    'sec-fetch-user': '?1',
    'upgrade-insecure-requests': '1',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/108.0.0.0 Mobile Safari/537.36',
}

payload : { 'username':'danielmantha'}
response = requests.post('https://gmail.inputekno.com/', cookies=cookies, headers=headers,data=payload)
```

Comment: There is no `POST` because the emails are generated by their Javascript code. https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/rulnoveid/CodeBlog@main/gmail%20trick/trick.js

Comment: you can either replicate the JavaScript logic with python [it looks fairly simple], or use selenium to interact with the page...why are you trying to scrape this btw?

Comment: thanks for the explanation, because I found some websites that can't use this request-based method, then I'm curious to make a scraping because I'm learning this

Answer (score 0):

As [CharlesHan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11514907/charles-han?tab=activity&sort=comments) commented,

> There is no POST because the emails are generated by their Javascript code. https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/rulnoveid/CodeBlog@main/gmail%20trick/trick.js

So, there's no way to **scrape** this particular data with requests-based methods.

---

If you *really* wanted to, there's [selenium](https://www.scrapingbee.com/blog/selenium-python/) [and other web-automation tools]. You could use [`scrapeGmailDotTrix`](https://pastebin.com/tgC4EpGZ) [short version below] - e.g., calling *`scrapeGmailDotTrix('somename')`* will scrape and return a list of the generated emails from the site after entering `somename` [in the input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtVbv.png).

```py
### full version at https://pastebin.com/tgC4EpGZ
## YOU MUST DOWNLOAD CHROMEDRIVER.EXE FOR THIS ##
## https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads ##

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def scrapeGmailDotTrix(username: str, wait_start=10, wait_op=200):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    driver.get('https://gmail.inputekno.com/')

    WebDriverWait(driver, wait_start).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((
            By.XPATH, '//input[@id="username"][@type="text"]')))

    driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, '//input[@id="username"][@type="text"]'
    ).send_keys(str(username))

    WebDriverWait(driver, wait_op).until(
        EC.text_to_be_present_in_element_value(
            (By.XPATH, '//textarea[@id="emails"]'),
            '.'.join(str(username))))

    return [em.strip() for em in driver.find_element(
        By.XPATH, '//textarea[@id="emails"]'
    ).get_attribute('value').splitlines()]
```

[The [full version](https://pastebin.com/tgC4EpGZ) has error-handling and precautionary waits to load input, etc.]

However, if you just want to generate emails the same way, this method is unnecessarily convoluted.

---

In contrast, [the main JavaScript logic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mZb4.png) is fairly simple to replicate with python:

```py
def gmailTrix_gen(uname:str):
    if len(uname) > 1: 
        head, tail = uname[0], uname[1:]
        for item in gmailTrix_gen(tail):
            yield head + item
            yield head + '.' + item
    else: yield uname

def gmailTrix_list(username:str):
    return [f'{gu}@gmail.com' for gu in gmailTrix_gen(username)]
```

For example, `gmailTrix_list('rand')` will return ([just like the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqjdR.png)):

> ```py
> ['rand@gmail.com', 'r.and@gmail.com', 'ra.nd@gmail.com', 'r.a.nd@gmail.com', 
>  'ran.d@gmail.com', 'r.an.d@gmail.com', 'ra.n.d@gmail.com', 'r.a.n.d@gmail.com']
> ```

Comment: thanks for the explanation, because I found some websites that can't use this request-based method, then I'm curious to make a scraping because I'm learning about this, and thank you for your help to convert the code to python

Comment: @AJilRichardo I see....since you're interested in the scraping methods, I've added a selenium solution as well. Hope it helps